# Am i missing (not covering) any cases in this code (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

```
function Scholarship(input){
    let income = input.shift();
    let avgGrade = input.shift();
    let minSalary = input.shift();

    let isExcellent = false;
    let isSocial = false;

    let socialSch = 0 ;
    let excellentSch = 0 ;

    if (avgGrade >= 5.50) {
        isExcellent = true;
        excellentSch = avgGrade * 25;
    } 

    if (income <= minSalary && avgGrade >= 4.50) {
        isSocial = true;
        socialSch = minSalary * 0.35;
    }

    if ((isSocial == false) && (isExcellent == false)){
        console.log("You cannot get a scholarship!");
    } else if (excellentSch >= socialSch){
        console.log(`You get a scholarship for excellent results ${Math.floor(excellentSch)} BGN`);
    } else if (socialSch > excellentSch){
        console.log(`You get a Social scholarship ${Math.floor(socialSch)} BGN`);
    }

}

Scholarship([number, number, number]);
```

All input numbers(data) are positive.

There should be a mistake somewhere in my logic!
Maybe i am missing to check for some other cases.

Comment: Can you elaborate further on what the goals of this code are? Also, I'm curious as to why you have three variables set to "input.shift()". That means you're taking the value of "input" as an array and removing the first entry, then assigning that to three different variables. Was that the goal?

Comment: Maybe you're getting strings and just need to use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` to convert them to proper values.

Comment: I added the input from an array

Comment: @JLowther err, `shift()` removes the first element.  Subsequent calls to shift would not return the same value, because the previous first element is removed.

Comment: @Alexander can you elaborate on why you think there is a mistake?

Comment: before the last `if ... else if...` do a `console.log(isSocial, isExcellent, excellentSch, socialSch);` and you will see

Comment: The goal is to check if a person can get a scholarship or not.

Comment: @Taplar i know there is a mistake because this is a homework for university and when i put the code in a judge system, the system tells me if there are any mistakes and if i am missing something

Comment: Let me rephrase my question.  We don't know what your code is supposed to do.  We therefore, don't know what is not working.  You need to explain to use, what it is supposed to do, and what you are seeing that to you is saying something is not working.

Comment: Lol i just fixed it! Do i need to delete the post now ?

Comment: @Taplar I admittedly didn't realize that would alter the array. Thanks!